# sql min function and other column

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to know if it is possible to add another column to a select statement that contain an aggregate function like min, max ...

example :

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(salary) FROM users;
```

is this statement correct in the sql standard(in mysql its work );
its work in mysql, but i think i read somewhere that if i put an aggregate function in the select clause, i can't put anything but an aggregate function or if there is a group by, the grouped column can be in the select clause (in mysql)

---

**EDIT** :

```
User(user_id, name, last_name, salary)
```

i want to select the `user_id, name, (maximum salary column)` from the `User` table; is it possible to do it without sub query?

User Table

```
User_id, Name, Salary

| 1 | user1 | last1 | 500  |   |
|---|-------|-------|------|---|
| 2 | user2 | last2 | 1000 |   |
| 3 | user3 | last3 | 750  |   |
|   |       |       |      |   |
```

the output must be the `user_id, username, lastname, and salary of the user who have the max salary`, so here the ouput must be :

```
 2 user2 last2 1000
```

---

Comment: Depend on what you want to do, mysql doesnt folllow ansi standard regarding aggregated functions and group by so you can do some shortcuts not allowed in other db.

Comment: @scaisEdge it i use group by, it will return the max(salary) for each tuple user_id, name which is the same as using `SELECT user_id, name, salary`

Comment: btw you should show us sample data and expected output. This question can be aswer different depending on what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Told you there are different solutions depending on what you want....

no group by, no subquery, Easy cake

```
select * 
from users
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Even when I got the accepted answer I overlook the ties case @ThorstenKettner solution handles

Answer (score 13):

To start with: No,

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(salary) FROM users;
```

is not standard-compliant. You are using an aggregate function (`MAX`) without a `GROUP BY` clause. By doing so you tell the DBMS to aggregate all records to one single result row. Now what do you tell the DBMS to show in this result row? The maximum salary found in the table (`MAX(salary)`) and *the* `user_id`. However, there is no *the* `user_id`; there are possibly many different `user_id` in the table. This violates the SQL standard. MySQL takes the liberty to interpret the non-aggregated `user_id` as *any* `user_id` (arbitrarily picked).

So even though the query runs, it's result is usually not the desired one.

This query:

```
SELECT user_id, name, MAX(salary) FROM users GROUP BY user_id;
```

on the other hand is standard-compliant. Let's see again what this query does: This time there is a `GROUP BY` clause telling the DBMS you want one result row per `user_id`. For each `user_id` you want to show: *the* `user_id`, *the* `name`, and the maximum `salary`. All these are valid expressions; *the* `user_id` is the `user_id` itself, *the* name is the one user name associated with the `user_id`, and the maximum `salary` is the user's maximum salary. The unaggregated column `name` is allowed, because it is functionally dependent on the grouped-by `user_id`. Many DBMS don't support this, though, because it can get extremely complicated to determine whether an expression is functionally dependent on the group or not.

As to how to show the user record with the maximum salary, you need a limiting clause. MySQL provides `LIMIT` for this, which can get you the first n rows. It doesn't deal with ties however.

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1;
```

is

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY salary FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

in standard SQL.

In order to deal with ties, however, as in

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY salary FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

you need a subquery in MySQL, because `LIMIT` doesn't support this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM users);
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at an example:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+---------+----------+
| user_id | salary   |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | 42000.00 |
|       2 | 39000.00 |
|       3 | 50000.00 |
+---------+----------+

mysql> SELECT user_id, MAX(salary) FROM users;
+---------+-------------+
| user_id | MAX(salary) |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |    50000.00 |
+---------+-------------+
```

What's up with that? User 1 is not the user that has a salary of 50000.00.

```
mysql> SELECT user_id, MAX(salary), MIN(SALARY) FROM users;
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| user_id | MAX(salary) | MIN(SALARY) |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 |    50000.00 |    39000.00 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

User 1 is also not the one with 39000.00. This is getting fishy, right?

When you use aggregate functions, they only apply to the column you use the function in. The user_id column doesn't magically know which row that max value came from, and show the corresponding user_id.

In that example, I query both the MAX and MIN salary. But these belong to different users! Which user_id should be shown, even if the user_id could automatically be from the row where the aggregate value comes from?

And what if two users have the same salary, which are tied for the max salary? Which user_id should be displayed?

And what if you use an aggregate function that doesn't return a value that exists on any single row?

```
mysql> SELECT user_id, AVG(salary) FROM users;
+---------+--------------+
| user_id | AVG(salary)  |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 | 43666.666667 |
+---------+--------------+
```

Here's the explanation: an aggregate function causes the result to be reduced to one single row, after reading the whole group of rows. A column that is not inside an aggregate function (like user_id here) takes its value from some arbitrary row in the group of rows. Arbitrary does not mean random—in practice, it tends to be the first MySQL row reads in the group. But there's no guarantee that'll always be the case.

How useful is this? Not very. In other databases, it's not a valid query, and it will literally generate an error.

In fact, MySQL 5.7 changed the behavior, by enforcing a rule that disallows ambiguous queries. If you try to run the query above on MySQL 5.7, it'll generate an error:

> ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'test.users.user_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

There's an option to make it act like earlier versions of MySQL. For more information on this, read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

As a matter of trivia, SQLite is another database that allows this kind of arbitrary result. Only in SQLite, the value of user_id would come from the *last* row read in the group. Go figure.

Comment: thank you for this valuable answer, but can you give me a solution to this problem?

Comment: I like this explanation very much. The misconception of the non-aggregated user_id in the query can't possibly be made any more obvious.

Comment: @karim, Juan Carlos gives the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
SELECT id,
       salary
  FROM (SELECT id,
               salary,
               MAX(salary) over ([partition by] [order by] dept) mx_sal
          FROM your_tbl)
 WHERE salary = mx_sal;
```