# sql min function and other column for sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

For sqlite I see that such query return correct result:

```
CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                   user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                   salary INTEGER NOT NULL);
insert into users (user_id, salary) values (1, 42000);
insert into users (user_id, salary) values (2, 39000);
insert into users (user_id, salary) values (3, 50000);
```

```
sqlite> SELECT user_id, MAX(salary) FROM users;
3|50000
sqlite> SELECT user_id, MIN(salary) FROM users;
2|39000
```

but looks like for mysql for example works in other way:

[sql min function and other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793562/sql-min-function-and-other-column)

and return `1|50000`.

Is it sqlite extension or may be mysql wrong in this case and this standard behaviour for SQL implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is *not* "correct" in SQLite.  SQLite extends its functionality to support these types of non-standard queries.  This is clearly an extension of functionality, and one I wish it did not do.

The queries are non-standard because there is an unaggregated column in the `SELECT` (`id`) but the query is an aggregation query (because of the `MIN()`/`MAX()`).  The more recent versions of MySQL with the default settings correctly reject this query as not syntactically correct.  Older versions of MySQL return a value of `id` from an arbitrary row.  SQLite has extended the definition of SQL for this special case and brings back the value of `id` that corresponds to the maximum or minimum salary.

In both databases, the better approach is:

```
SELECT user_id, salary as max_salary
FROM users
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

and:

```
SELECT user_id, salary as min_salary
FROM users
ORDER BY salary ASC
LIMIT 1;
```